# Python lambda: filter(lambda (v,p): v!=p).count(). Syntax error & <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, lambda

I know

```
labelsAndPredictions = tst_dataRDD.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)
testErr = labelsAndPredictions.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(tst_dataRDD.count())
```

has syntax error because Python3 doesn't support using tuple in lambda. I'm wondering how to convert it to the right syntax so it works for python3. Thank you.
I have tried

```
filter(lambda v,p: v!=p).count()
```

But I got another error message TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'.
I have no idea how to solve it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: filter is just giving you one argument. if you know that the object filter is giving you  is  a tuple do `filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1]).count()`

Comment: `filter()` requires both a function and an iterable to filter like a list. You're just passing a function, so it's not really clear what you are trying to do. I *think* you are after something more like `sum(v!=p for v, p in  my_list_of_tuples)`

Comment: Hi I've reposted the code above.Thank you!